# Epsilon Delta Limit DNE proof

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

I am having difficuly proving that the limit $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{|x|}$$ does not exist using the negation of the epsilon-delta definition. I have seen a similar question answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3113342/showing-the-limit-as-x-to-0-of-the-function-x-x-does-not-exist) but I am having trouble applying the same logic to the negation of the definition instead of finding a contradiction.

This is the definition I am trying to use:
$$\forall L\in\mathbb{R},\exists\epsilon>0\text{ s.t }\forall\delta>0,\exists x\in\mathbb{R} \text{ s.t } 0<|x-a|<\delta\text{ and } |F(x)-L|\ge\epsilon$$

Comment: It seems like the answers in the linked question also answer this question.  Namely: given $L$, we show that $\epsilon := 1$ will work.  To show this, suppose given $\delta > 0$.  Then in the case $L \ge 0$, $x := -\frac{\delta}{2}$ will work; in the case $L < 0$, $x := +\frac{\delta}{2}$ will work.